# Род имен существительных.

Tags: род

Какого рода слова: румяна, сутки, джинсы?

Answer (score 3):

У таких существительных род не определяется, потому что у них нет формы единственного числа. Глаголы, причастия, прилагательные в сочетании с этими существительными Вы употребите во множественном числе:румяна яркие, сутки пролетели, джинсы потёртые. Для этого род знать совсем не нужно. 
Категория рода всегда есть у существительных, имеющих форму единственного числа, даже у несклоняемых, так как это необходимо для правильного их употребления в сочетании с другими частями речи.

Answer (score 1):

Для школы род этих существительных действительно не определяется.

В продвинутом разборе румяна причисляют к женскому роду по форме родительного падежа. 
Сутки - тоже, хотя по внешним признакам возможно, что и к среднему, но в дореволюционной орфографии писалось "кругл**ыя** сутки"("Гaлдежъ стоялъ, дeйствительно, круглыя сутки. Я ходилъ по Вичкe -- и зaвидовaлъ" - найдено в интернете), что является признаком женского рода. Впрочем, постараюсь уточнить.

В мужском роде было бы "румянов и сутков". 
Что касается слова "джинсы", то в связи с неустоявшейся формой родительного ("джинсов" или "джинс") сказать наверняка нельзя. Скорее все-таки первое: джинсов, поэтому слово логично отнести к мужскому роду.

//-----------

Зализняк дает сутки - ж., румяна - ср., джинсы - м. 
Я ему верю, но не уверен, что его подход - единственно правильный.
Особенно с румянами. То как объясняет Марк Из критики не выдерживает. Возможно, есть какой-то более вразумительный критерий.

На лингве мне предложили румяны - ж, румяна - ср., что еще более сомнительно, ибо род гипотетической *основы* ([одна] румяна - она) по идее меняться не должен... Надо искать первоисточники...

Ещё.
"слова ножницы, пени (штраф), (жалобы) (устар.), сутки соотнесены с сущ. жен. р.:"
http://rusgram.narod.ru/1194-1215.html
Здесь логика более или менее понятна. Во всяком случае она соответствует историческим правилам.

Черн*ыя* чернила:
http://books.google.ru/books?id=4mFGAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA5-PT314&lpg=RA5-PT314&dq=%22%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%8F+%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%22&source=bl&ots=KyIqwAJEIz&sig=ioo5pV20bUEGw_5AKOKLIIjndjE&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=_Um8UYSyFMTo4QTy_oHQCg&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%8F%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0&f=false

Опровергает всю представленную логику отнесения румян к ср. р. 
Не сам факт разумеется - с этим надо еще разбираться.

А у Зализняка: чернила - средний род. Вот и приехали. ))) При всем к нему уважении, Словарю Академiи Россiйcкой я доверяю больше.

Блин... И в том же источнике: "чернило" - ср. р. С примером "орешковыя чернила". Что-то я совсем запутался... Или в те времена допускалось написание "-ыя" для среднего рода? Тогда зачем вообще вся эта катавасия, которой гимназистов изводили? Ведь это считалось грубой ошибкой...

А вот еще насчет суток (параграф 334, последняя фраза): "Свѣчей отпускать въ казармы на каждыхъ десять человѣкъ въ каждые сутки по двѣ, на одни зимніе мѣсяцы."

http://books.google.ru/books?id=5640AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA317&dq=%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%A3%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9+%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B2%D1%8A+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8B%D1%85%D1%8A+%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%A3%D0%BA%D1%8A+%D0%B2%D1%8A+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%A3,+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8+%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B5+%D0%BC%D1%A3%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%86%D1%8B.&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=1Fi8UYDEMebE4gThjoDYCA&ved=0CDUQuwUwAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%A3%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D1%8A%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8B%D1%85%D1%8A%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%A3%D0%BA%D1%8A%20%D0%B2%D1%8A%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%A3%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D1%A3%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%86%D1%8B.&f=false

(Подсказали на лингве, спасибо еще раз)

Все, один вопрос, кажется, решился. У меня заскок был. 
В среднем роде тоже нормативно писалось IЯ/ЫЯ. Так что с "круглыя сутки" и "черныяя чернила" - не аргумент. 
Получается, что вопрос пока в состоянии обсуждения. Сутки и румяна претендуют и на женский, и на средний род. А если приянть во внимание "каждые сутки" - то и на мужской. А почему нет? носок - носки - носок. С[b]у[/b]ток - сутки - суток.

Всё, вынужден прерваться.

Comment: >В продвинутом разборе румяна причисляют к женскому роду по форме родительного падежа.

А каким образом из "румяна" получился ж. р.? На основании чего? Кто причисляет к женскому роду кроме вас (Даль только *румяны* к женскому относит, скорей всего, по той же логике, что и я)?

Кстати, этимологический словарь Семёнова к производным от "румяный" словам относит: *румяность, румяней, румяна* и **румяно**.

Comment: >А почему нет? носок - носки - носок. С[b]у[/b]ток - сутки - суток.

@behemothus, *носок* - как форма множественного числа - это сравнительно недавнее образование, которое до последнего времени считалось речевой ошибкой.

Comment: >носок - как форма множественного числа - это сравнительно недавнее образование,   
  
Источник? Насколько понимаю, это как раз весьма древнее образование, восходящее к двойственному числу. Глаз - тоже "недавнее"? А раньше было еще "рог".
   
Впрочем, не в этом дело. Даже если все так, как вы говорите, что это добавляет в понимании?

На остальное отвечать лениво. см. мой профиль. 
Я ищу ответ, мне пока неконструктивные критики не нужны.  
Столько всего написать - и не увидеть главную и вобщем-то единственную фактическую ошибку - насчет "ЫЯ/IЯ" в среднем роде, на чем все и строилось...

Comment: @behemothus, носки в русский народный костюм не входили. Источники в интернете утверждают, что данный предмет одежды появился в России только в 1815 году, но они не особо авторитетны, поэтому без ссылок. По отношению к носкам обуви или других предметов с выступающей частью, то по отношению к ним форму *пара носок сапогов* мне встречать не доводилось, только "носков". 

Про *глаз* и *рог* я тоже думал, но там в отличие от ср. р. ударение смещается *глазА, рогА*, а у румян в Им. п. ударение падает на корень.

Comment: ЦСЯ, прилаг. мн.ч. :

И.п. - мудрїи (м.) мудрая (ср.) мудрыя (ж.)

В.п. - мудрыя/-ыхъ (м.) мудрая (ср.) мудрыя (ж.)

Answer (score 1):

Если уж восстанавливать единственное число, то:

**Румяна** - это явно средний род (ср. *яйца-яиц, сёла-сёл* и т. д.). В женском роде не смогло бы появится  окончание "-а" в именительном падеже, так как в этом случае совпадали бы формы множественного и единственного числа (I скл) или в родительном было бы окончание "-ей" (III скл. *мышей, дверей* и пр.). В мужском же роде появилось бы окончание "-ов" в родительном. Единственное число - ***румяно*** (ср. с *белило*).

**Сутки** - женский род. Средний бы род давал окончание "-а" в именительном, а мужской "-ов" в родительном. Единственное число - ***сутка*** (ср. с *утка*)

**Джинсы** - зависит от ударения, *джинсЫ* - женский род от *джинса*, а *джИнсы* - мужской род, так есть окончание "-ов" в родительном падеже. Единственное число от джИнсы - ***джинс*** (ср. с *торт*)

Comment: >В женском роде не смогло бы появится окончание "-а" в именительном падеже, так как в этом случае совпадали бы формы множественного и единственного числа,   
 
Нет такого критерия. Ко всему прочему, совершенно умозрительное заключение, ибо сравниваются **несуществующие** формы. "Совпадать" просто не с чем. Марк Из, вы велосипед изобретаете, а надо всего лишь ознакомиться с любой дореволюционной грамматикой. Там всё есть. 

>Средний бы род давал окончание "-а" в именительном,  
  
Не факт. Окончание А для среднего рода множественного числа - сравнительно недавняя история. Румяна явно старше.

Comment: @behemothus, я не знаю какого рода они были этимологически, хотя они судя по всему были тех родов, что я и написал. Румяна почти наверняка были того же рода, что и белила, а слово "белило" до нас дошло.  
Учитывая, что среди меток, нет "этимологии", вывод лучше делать на основании особенностей русского языка, а не недошедших до нас  форм древнерусского. В современном русском же получается, что в ед. ч. из *румян* должно получится: *румяна* (ж.р), *румянь* (ж.р), *румян* (м. р) или *румяно* (ср. р) Метод исключения (см. ответ) оставляет только "румяно". Тот же принцип и в остальных случаях.

Comment: >я не знаю какого рода они были этимологически, хотя они судя по всему были тех родов, что я и написал  
  
"Суди дружок, не выше сапога". 
Марк Из, вы не находите, что после такого заявления, дискуссию можно сворачивать? 
Особенно на фоне заявлений про носки и румяна.
Вы действительно не знаете ничего того, что следовало бы использовать.

Comment: @behemothus, я нахожу, что слова "румяна" и "сутки" слишком древние для того, чтобы увидеть их изначальную форму в живую, а потому попытка исторического анализа здесь не имеет смысла, в чём можно убедится, например, почитав ваш ответ.

То, что *носок* как вариант мн. ч. стал допустимым лишь недавно можете почитать в сети по запросу "носков или носок", доказать же отсутствие невозможно, поэтому если найдёте упоминание носков в русском костюме до XIX века (для этих целей испльзовали онучи), пожалуйста сообщите. Название носки получили от *носки (передний конец) чулок*.

Comment: Щанс же, что при ошибочной логике я получу стопроцентное совпадение с Зализняком менее 4%, так что или мои рассуждения в целом совпадают с его, или я - экстрасенс.
 По какой логике румяна отнесены к ж.р., в первоначальном варианте ответа, вы так и не сказали.

Comment: >я нахожу, что слова "румяна" и "сутки" слишком древние для того,  
  
Так поищите еще форму слова "носки". Просите, я сейчас не располагаю временем, чтобы терять его на подобные разговоры про онучи и прочее. 
Что это добавляет в понимание того, каков род указанных слов?
Вы сказали, что думаете, это не более, чем Ваше мнение. Никакой приемлемой логикой не обосновали. Дальнейшее - "ффтопку".

>По какой логике румяна отнесены к ж.р....
  
Сказал. Другое дело, что сам потом усомнился, но, увы, не Вашей помощью. Зато Вы не сказали ничего конкретного.

Comment: >А если приянть во внимание "каждые сутки" - то и на мужской. А почему нет? носок - носки - носок. С[b]у[/b]ток - сутки - суток

@behemothus, вы стали делать вывод на основании исключения. Так как такая форма нехарактерна в русском языке, и до совсем недавнего времени вообще не нормативна. На что я и указал в комментарии.

 А логика тут самая обыкновенная, другой, для того чтобы установить какого рода эти слова в СОВРЕМЕННОМ русском языке - нет.